# continuously update the data in the angular material tables from an api

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I have an angular app in which I created a table using angular material and filling the data using an API. My code

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getChillerApiData();
  }

  getChillerApiData() {
    this.api.getFirstChillerData()
      .subscribe((first_data:any) => {
        this.first_api_data = first_data;
        this.putPrimaryPumpData();
      });
  }

  displayedColumns_primary_pump: string[] = ['Index', 'Pump', 'Frequecy', 'Mode'];
  dataSource_primary_pump = new MatTableDataSource<PrimaryPumpDataTable>()

  primary_pump_index = 1
  @ViewChild('table', { static: true }) primary_pump_table
  putPrimaryPumpData(){
    this.dataSource_primary_pump.data.push(
      {Index: this.primary_pump_index++, Pump: "P-1", Frequecy: String(this.first_api_data["Pr. Chw Pump 1 VFD F/B"]), Mode: String(this.first_api_data["Pr. Chw Pump 1 A/M status"])},
      {Index: this.primary_pump_index++, Pump: "Delta T", Frequecy: String(this.first_api_data["Chiller 1 evap Supply temp"] - this.first_api_data["Chiller 1  evap ret Temp"]).slice(0,4), Mode: ""},)
      this.primary_pump_table.renderRows();
  }

}
```

I am trying to fetch the data in `ngOnIt` and display it in table. I want this data to be updated every 1 min, by making API call every 1 minute. For that, I have added a function like

```
intervalId : any

  getRealTimeData() {
    this.getChillerApiData()
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      this.getChillerApiData();
    }, 1000);
  }
```

and calling this function in ngOnIt. Now I am able to get the latest data, but rows in my table are being appended with the new data. I want to update the rows in the table with the latest values from API instead of adding new rows.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: by update you mean completely replace the entire table data with new data or some fixed rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply replace the data do

```js
putPrimaryPumpData(){
    this.dataSource_primary_pump.data = [
      {Index: this.primary_pump_index++, Pump: "P-1", Frequecy: String(this.first_api_data["Pr. Chw Pump 1 VFD F/B"]), Mode: String(this.first_api_data["Pr. Chw Pump 1 A/M status"])},
      {Index: this.primary_pump_index++, Pump: "Delta T", Frequecy: String(this.first_api_data["Chiller 1 evap Supply temp"] - this.first_api_data["Chiller 1  evap ret Temp"]).slice(0,4), Mode: ""}
    ]
      this.primary_pump_table.renderRows();
  }
```

Comment: worked, thanks!! also I had to reset my index, I have done that

Answer (score 1):

You need to empty the old data from `this.dataSource_primary_pump.data` before pushing updated data.

```
putPrimaryPumpData(){
    this.dataSource_primary_pump.data = []; // empty data.
    this.dataSource_primary_pump.data.push(
      {Index: this.primary_pump_index++, Pump: "P-1", Frequecy: String(this.first_api_data["Pr. Chw Pump 1 VFD F/B"]), Mode: String(this.first_api_data["Pr. Chw Pump 1 A/M status"])},
      {Index: this.primary_pump_index++, Pump: "Delta T", Frequecy: String(this.first_api_data["Chiller 1 evap Supply temp"] - this.first_api_data["Chiller 1  evap ret Temp"]).slice(0,4), Mode: ""},)
      this.primary_pump_table.renderRows();
  }
```